# Stripe: Allow subscription without payment method

Tags: stripe-payments

We're using stripe as a payment gateway.

I'm trying to subscribe a customer to a plan. This plan has a 30 days trial period. So, we're delaying customer adds a source (payment method) details on its profile.

Nevertheless, when I'm trying to subscribe it to a plan, stripe is getting me this message:

> This customer has no attached payment source.

Is there any way to allow customer has no payment sources along trial period?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You can [create a subscription](https://stripe.com/docs/api/subscriptions/create) for a customer with no payment source, as long as there is nothing to bill immediately (e.g. because of a trial period, or because the plan is free, or because of a negative invoice item or coupon that reduces the first invoice's total to $0).

If you're getting this error message:

> This customer has no attached payment source.

it means that Stripe is trying to bill the customer, so you must be using a non-free plan without a trial period. I'd recommend checking your code and the plan's properties to make sure that this plan has a default trial period, or make sure that you include the [`trial_end`](https://stripe.com/docs/api/subscriptions/create#create_subscription-trial_end) parameter when creating the subscription.

Answer (score 27):

I ran into the same problem as @Jordi. My plan had a default trial period, but I was still getting the error mentioned in the question.

Instead of setting `trial_end` as @Ywain suggests, I set `trial_from_plan` to `true` when creating the subscription. That way I didn't have to set and/or calculate the length of the trial in my API call.

Comment: This should be the selected answer -- thanks @AAAton! :-)

Answer (score 10):

You can also use `default_incomplete` as the `payment_behavior` value. It allows to create a subscription for a customer with no payment method attached.

Stripe's documentation says:

> Use default_incomplete to create Subscriptions with status=incomplete when the first invoice requires payment, otherwise start as active.

Our subscription didn’t provide any trial period and it did the job in our case.

Comment: I think this is the same as the accepted answer. But much more straight forward. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think using `trial_period_days` is the best option. I can easily manage allowing people to subscribe a product for free/trial for 30/365 or any amount of days. Stripe will take care of the rest, like when the free/trial period will end and notifying for that.
Besides that, `trial_settings.end_behavior.missing_payment_method` flag can help free/trial end behaviour with options `cancel`, `pause`, `create_invoice`.
In my case, I used like below:

```
trial_period_days: 365, 
trial_settings.end_behavior.missing_payment_method: pause
```